# React sending wrong value in inline onClick event

Tags: reactjs, events, onclick

React 17.0.2. My application involves a small event calendar.

I am trying to make a function where to make an event, you can open the event window then click the date on the calendar and the date will change to the date you've clicked.

For some reason, after assigning each day an onClick event that passes its day, the function that is called receives the wrong day.

The calendar is drawn using a function that builds each weak in a for loop, but basically this is what I am doing.

```
function selectedDate(day){
     console.log(day)
     setEventDay(day)
}

function renderWeek(){
     var week = []
     for(this week){
        var dayOfTheWeek = calcDayOfTheWeek()
        week.push(<div onClick={()=> 
                       {selectedDate(dayOfTheWeek)}}> 
                   dayOfTheWeek 
                  </div>)
       
     }
}
function renderMonth(){
    for(months){
      month.push(renderWeek())
    }
}
```

dayOfTheWeek  is working because my calendar displays perfectly, all dates correct within the div. But the selectedDate() function always receives the wrong day value.

[Image of Calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2v2F5.png)

When I click on day 1,2,3,4,5, console.log() prints 5 for all of them.
When I click on day 6,7,8,9,10,11,12, console.log() prints 12 for all of them.

Any help would be great. If I resolve I will come back to update but I cannot understand why the callback would not have the same value it is displaying just fine in the same element as it is being created by React. Thanks

Edit1:

Even stranger, adding the attribute `data-value={offset+1}` to my divs, the data-value is correct. So no idea why the event function is passing the wrong value!

EDIT2:

I did find a workaround. If I change my code to be this, I get the right value. But I know it's the wrong way to resolve this.

```
week.push(<div data-value={dayOfTheWeek} onClick={()=> 
                       {selectedDate(e.target.getAttribute('data-value'))}}> 
                   dayOfTheWeek 
                  </div>)
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because by the time you make a click, your loop has finished and `dayOfTheWeek` is the last value in the loop. The click handler simply refers directly to `dayOfTheWeek`; therefore, it always has the final value.

You can use a closure to close over the scope to protect the variable in the click event.

```
(day)=> {
    week.push(<div onClick={()=> 
                   {selectedDate(day)}}> 
               day 
              </div>)
}(dayOfTheWeek)
```

Comment: Hmm, I did try this after reading your comment but I am still getting the same result. (Thank you for commenting and helping) This basically turns it into an immediately invoked function, right?